# UpdatePanel not refreshing when used in modal popup in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

My site uses a master-page which I have placed the modal popup div (id="myModal") on hidden by default. I'm using twitter bootstrap modal popup (modal.js) and jQuery.load() to populate the body of #myModal with another aspx page called Feedback.aspx.

The modal pops up as expected and displays the feedback.aspx content (which is a complete page including doctype, HTML, head and body tags... maybe it shouldn't be?), but because it's not displaying within an iframe, when I submit the page, it does a PostBack and refreshes the parent with the entire feedback.aspx page.

I'd like the feedback.aspx to simply refresh within the modal popup instead of the entire parent page.

I have tried wrapping the entire body content of the feedback.aspx page in an UpdatePanel (with ScriptManager) and when I click the submit button now, the data gets saved to the database, and the modal window stays open, but my ModalAlertBox message doesn't display. I'm assuming my modal window isn't updating.

I've tried adding updatepanel.update() to my submitbutton.click event, but it still doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

**MasterPage:**

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>    
    <div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

**Feedback.aspx (Used as #myModal content):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<form ...>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ModalScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ModalUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnModalSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
           ...
           <div id="ModalAlertBox" class="alert" runat="server" visible="false">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
               <asp:Label ID="lblModalMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
           </div>
           ...
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Feedback.aspx.vb**

```
Protected Sub btnModalSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnModalSubmit.Click
    Try
        GetAccount(_Account)
        If _Account.Exists Then
            ... Save Logic ...
            lblModalMsg.Text = "Success Msg."
        Else
            lblModalMsg.Text = "Fail Msg."
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        clsExceptionHandler.log(ex)
        lblModalMsg.Text = "Unexpected Error Msg."
    End Try
    Me.ModalAlertBox.Visible = True
    Me.ModalUpdatePanel.Update()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved. I wrapped only the ModalAlertBox within the UpdatePanel instead of the entire form and it has fixed the issue.

```
....    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ModalUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnModalSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="ModalAlertBox" class="alert" runat="server" visible="false">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <asp:Label ID="lblModalMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
....
```